# Sql query to fetch most recent record upto 10 and order by filed where row rank is mentioned

Tags: php, mysql, sql, subquery, greatest-n-per-group

Following is my table in Mysql. I want to fetch record of latest date in field "rank_date" and display result by order 1 to 10 based on order # in filed "drama_rank"

[image]

Comment: Please post sample data as SQL INSERT statement, not picture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter with a subquery, then `order by`:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where rank_date = (select max(rank_date) from mytable)
order by drama_rank
```

Alternatively, assuming MySQL 8.0, you can use window functions:

```
select *
from (
    select t.*, rank() over(order by rank_date desc) rn
    from mytable t
) t
where rn = 1
order by drama_rank
```

Comment: select t.*
from mytable t
where rank_date = (select max(rank_date) from mytable)
order by drama_rank

Above code worked perfectly. I wish i had asked here before waisting 2 hrs trying different queries. Thanks mate.